# Why Can I Not Replicate the NumPy v1.13.dev0 Manual Examples

Tags: python, numpy

As an example I am reading through the following:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/new-iterator-ufunc.html

So I run a bit of code on my computer using iPython shown for example in the manual as:

```
   def iter_add_itview(x, y, out=None):
        it = np.nditer([x,y,out], [],
                    [['readonly'],['readonly'],['writeonly','allocate']])

        (a, b, c) = it.itviews
        np.add(a, b, c)

        return it.operands[2]
```

Which per the example results in tests cases as follows:

```
In [10]: a = np.arange(1000000,dtype='f4').reshape(100,100,100).T
In [12]: b = np.arange(10000,dtype='f4').reshape(100,100,1).T
In [11]: c = np.arange(10000,dtype='f4').reshape(1,100,100).T

In [4]: timeit np.add(np.add(np.add(a,b), c), a)
1 loops, best of 3: 99.5 ms per loop

In [9]: timeit iter_add_itview(iter_add_itview(iter_add_itview(a,b), c), a)
10 loops, best of 3: 29.3 ms per loop
```

SO naturally I want to try this excitement for myself on using NumPy1.12.1 in Python 2.7 on Linux with an Intel chipset, the only problem is I consistently get null results for the exact same experimental setups as in the example above:

```
In [12]: timeit np.add(np.add(np.add(a,b), c), a)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop

In [13]: timeit iter_add_itview(iter_add_itview(iter_add_itvie
    ...: w(a,b), c), a)
100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop
```

In this case I was supposed to be seeing improvements from buffer cache optimization.

Why is it that I am not able to replicate a section of the dev manual for a updated NumPy version using a legacy version of the code?

Comment: Those improvements have probably been folded into the standard ufunc implementation already.

Comment: so the dev manual is a release ahead but out of date?

Comment: They don't take NEPs out of the docs just because they've been implemented. They just put them under the "Implemented NEPs" section, like this one is.

Comment: I think that this is actually still under 'enhancement proposals'

Comment: .. it would be great for me to figure that out

Comment: Go to the [NEP overview page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/neps/index.html), and you'll see this one in the Implemented section.

Comment: Note that the document you're reading is from 2010. It's over 6 years old.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142940/discussion-between-oliver-and-user2357112).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be clear the `In[4]` and `[9]` times are copied from that 6 yr old document.  The `[12][13]` times are from your own tests (and basically the same as what I get).  I haven't studied that old `dev` document, but have run the `np.nditer` examples on

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.nditer.html

and know that `nditer` does not normally speed code.  This iterator is meant to be used in C level code, and its exposure at the Python level is a convenience.  It lets us test ideas in Python code before moving them to C or Cython.  Note the Cython example at the end. Even so, I found I could get better speed in a simple multiplication case by using Cython  memoryviews.

`np.ndindex` is one of the few `numpy` functions that uses `np.nditer` in Python code.  I've occasionally suggested a similar pattern to produce depth limited iteration.

So don't worry too much about mastering `np.nditer`.