# NumPy array iterator: use nditer or not?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, iterator

I'm new to Python. I understand that there are two ways to iterate through a numpy array.

First way,

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
for i in a:
    print i
```

Second way,

```
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
for i in np.nditer(a):
    print i
```

If i don't need any fancy utilities provided by `nditer`, does it matter which way to choose? `nditer`'s [manual page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html) is helpful, but it doesn't explain my question. I guess the first way is syntactic sugar of the second way? I'd like confirmation from you guys.

Comment: if it's a 1D array I don't think there is any difference, there is however a difference for n-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Chance are, you don't want to iterate at all - the whole point in numpy is to push the iteration into the C code or even vectorized CPU instructions.

Comment: That iteration page is best seen as a stepping stone to using nditer in compiled code.  It isn't very useful in python code.  There's no speed advantage.

Comment: Previous answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42996696; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018527; 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43688331

Comment: @Eric in my particular project, I'm iterating through the array to check if any of them is NaN. If yes, replace it with another value. Is there better way of doing it? thanks

Comment: @hpaulj I like your answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/43005985/901925 Although it's a pity that the title and the question itself on that page provides little clue of your answer about `nditer`. It's hard to be found imo

Comment: `nditer` does let you change the value of the iteration variable, as demonstrated in https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/arrays.nditer.html#modifying-array-values.  But replacing `nan` is better done with whole array masking (if possible).  Ask a new question if needed.

Comment: You can do that with `x[np.isnan(x)] = the_other_value`

Comment: @Eric nice solution!